# Convert a text file into a nested json in python

Tags: python, json

My data looks like below. This is the input file:

```
storeId,id,itemId,description
123,1,101,item_1
123,1,102,item_2
123,1,103,item_3
123,2,201,item_4
123,2,202,item_5
```

I want to parse it using Python and write the JSON equivalent so that the information is re-written to a file in the following format:

```
[{
    "storeId": 123,
    "itemType": [{
        "id": 1,
        "items": [{
            "itemId": 101,
            "description": "item_1"
        }, {
            "itemId": 102,
            "description": "item_2"
        }, {
            "itemId": 103,
            "description": "item_3"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "images": [{
            "itemId": 201,
            "description": "item_4"
        }, {
            "itemId": 202,
            "description": "item_5"
        }]
    }]
}]
    enter code here
```

I am confused how I can achieve this. Can anyone help me, please? I am very new to python.

Comment: Show us your current python code.

Comment: I'm glad that you're learning Python, but unfortunately SO is not a free code-writing service.  You are going to need to put forth some effort before someone is going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools, csv
data = [[int(b) if b.isdigit() else b for b in i] for i in csv.reader(open('filename.csv'))][1:]
headers = ['storeId', 'itemType', 'id', 'items', 'itemId', 'description']
def create_structure(d, headers = headers):
  c = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
  return [{headers[0]:a, headers[1]:create_structure([i for _, *i in b], headers = headers[2:]) if len(headers[2:]) > 2 else [dict(zip(headers[2:], i)) for _, *i in b]} for a, b in c]
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(create_structure(data), indent = 4))
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "storeId": 123,
    "itemType": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "items": [
                {
                    "itemId": 101,
                    "description": "item_1"
                },
                {
                    "itemId": 102,
                    "description": "item_2"
                },
                {
                    "itemId": 103,
                    "description": "item_3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "items": [
                {
                    "itemId": 201,
                    "description": "item_4"
                },
                {
                    "itemId": 202,
                    "description": "item_5"
                }
            ]
        }
     ]
   }
]
```